# ¿Cómo ordenar los números de un vector de mayor a menor?

Tags: c#, array, bucle-for, ordenar

Estoy empezando a programar y en los ejercicios del temario hay uno que pone el ordenar los números de un vector de mayor a menor mediante un *InPutBox*.

El problema es que he intentado varios maneras como el `Array.Sort` pongo el código a continuación porque seguramente tenga bastantes fallos y así aprendo cómo solucionar errores lógicos:

```
string texto;
int[] ordenarvector = new int[10];
Array.Sort(ordenarvector);

for (int i = 0; i < ordenarvector[10]; i++)
{
    texto = Interaction.InputBox("Introduce el número", "Vector", "");
}
Array.Reverse(ordenarvector);
MessageBox.Show("La posición es " + ordenarvector);
```

Como digo estoy aprendiendo y aún no termino de entender cómo podría hacerlo, cualquier ayuda es bienvenida, intentaré aprender lo máximo posible.

Un saludo y gracias de ante mano.

Comment: Cierto disculpa, es en C#

Comment: sort ordena una vez que el array esta lleno.. no antes... ;)

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! La documentacion es tu gran amigo...

Comment: Igual, lo interesante seria que aprendar a ordenar por vos mismo, antes de usar una funcion que ordene por vos...

Comment: @Aarón, hola podrias por favor marcar la respuesta que mas te sirvio como aceptada, y si hubo alguna otra que gusto o que podrias usar alternativamente, darle un voto positivo

Answer (score 1):

puedes usar insertion sort para eso, es un algortimo facil de entender aqui te pongo el codigo para que lo organize de mayor a menor y aqui puede leer la teoria usada en insertion sort, [insertion sort](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/insertion-sort/)

```
int[] arr = { 8, 99, 78, 99, 674 };
            int n = arr.Length;
            for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i)
            {
                int key = arr[i];
                int j = i - 1;

                
                while (j >= 0 && arr[j] < key)
                {
                    arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
                    j = j - 1;
                }
                arr[j + 1] = key;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(arr[i]+" ");
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Existen muchísimos métodos de ordenamiento aquí te dejo el algoritmo de ordenamiento por el **método burbuja**, que es el método más sencillo de entender y el más básico:

```
int tmp = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < arreglo.Count; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < arreglo.Count - 1; j++)
    {
        if(arreglo[j] < arreglo[j + 1])
        {
           tmp = arreglo[j];
           arreglo[j] = arreglo[j + 1];
           arreglo[j + 1] = tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

El **método burbuja** es un sencillo **algoritmo de ordenamiento**. Funciona revisando cada elemento de la lista que va a ser ordenada con el siguiente, intercambiandóqlos de posición si están en el orden equivocado.

Aquí te dejo alguno de los **métodos de ordenamiento** que existen:

**BubbleSort**

**SelectionSort**

**InsertionSort**

**MergeSort**

**QuickSort**

**HeapSort**

**RadixSort**

Y muchos otros....

Cada uno de estos algoritmos tiene sus ventajas y desventajas, y diferentes modos de implementación, algunos emplean la **recursividad** y otros la **iteración**. Además, de que por supuesto unos son mas óptimos que otro en cuanto a velocidad de ejecución.

Empieza aprendiendo el **método burbuja** que de todos es el más fácil, y ve saltando poco a poco a otros **algoritmos de ordenamiento** a medida que vayas aprendiendo más sobre estos. Puedes obtener más información sobre **algoritmos de ordenamiento** en Internet.